# Alias of SQL Server 2012 Instance

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have 2 instances on database server(SQL Server 2012) MHDSDB01 and user_DB1. I am sysadmin on MHDSDB01 instance. I do not have access to user_DB1. They both are on the same server. They both share same mdf and ldf files.(It means both are same). For both instances Serverproperty('computernamephysicalnetbios') results to 'MHDSDB01'. They are not cluster nodes. They are not mirror since databases on both instances are exactly similar. In SQL Server configuration manager there are no alias present. Can you please help understanding relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely certain what you are asking but here is where I think you are going.

Each instance is a separate "SQL Servers". The 2 are not directly related but I do believe that they share some core files. So long as you have sufficient resources to maintain both instances, I would treat them as if they were on 2 different physical servers.

"computernamephysicalnetbios" is the name of the physical server not sql server so will be the same for each instance. A list of the properties is here: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) Try SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') to see the name of the instance you are currently connected too.

Comment: Yes for both instances, server name is MHDSDB01 only

Comment: The Physical Server is named MHDSDB01. Because of this the DEFAULT instance will also be named MHDSDB01 but the named instance will be MHDSDB01\user_DB1.

Comment: Actually Its looking that , MHDSDB01 is the only instance. But I am confused how user_DB1 is created ?  I have access on MHDSDB01 but not on user_DB1. They are not looking different instances in SQL Server configuration manager.

Comment: Can you attach a screen cap of what you are seeing?

Comment: I'm sorry but unfortunately I can't attach since it is screenshot functionality is disabled in my org. But here are some observations : 1. I checked server property by right clicking on server in object explorer on both entities, it has same computer name but different server name.
2. select SERVERPROPERTY('computernamephysicalnetbios') gives result MHDSDB01
3. select @@SERVICENAME gives MSSQLSERVER2012
4. Database property - mirroring - disabled (Not mirrored)
5. SELECT * FROM fn_virtualservernodes()  returns null
6. SELECT 'IsClustered', SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') returns 0

Comment: Run SELECT @@SERVERNAME and SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')

Comment: Both are giving me same result 'MHMSDB01' on both MHMSDB01 and user_DB1.